# How to reset ONLY a specific ngModelGroup fields in Angular 2.1.1?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

i have this simple code:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
   <fieldset ngModelGroup="cliente">
      // inputs with ngModel
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset ngModelGroup="enderecos">
      // inputs with ngModel
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset ngModelGroup="contatos">
      // inputs with ngModel
   </fieldset>
</form>

// My submit method
submit(form: NgForm) {
  if(form.valid) {
    // save
    // reset method
    form.reset();
  }
}
```

When i call the method form.reset(), Angular reset all the fields by default.

My question is: Does have any chance to reset ONLY a specific ngModelGroup like "contatos" or "enderecos" and not all the form inputs?

Thanks in advise.

Comment: I think i solve done this on my method: form.controls['contato'].reset();

Answer (score 8):

I think i solve done this on my method:

```
form.controls['contato'].reset();
```

'contato' is a ngModelGroup on my form.

Comment: Hi, you can also try in this way- `form.controls.reset({'contato':null});` [link] https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls